# Why isn't string parameter being routed to an action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my MVC5 application I am trying to pass a string to an action.

In `PodcastsController` I have an action called `Tagged`:

```
public ActionResult Tagged(string tag)
{
    return View();
}
```

For example, if I wanted pass the string `Test`to the `Tagged` action, it would look like this in the url:

**/Podcasts/Tagged/Test**

I have a route set up like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       "Podcasts",
       "Podcasts/Tagged/{tag}",
       new { controller = "Podcasts", action = "Tagged", tag = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

**Edit** I am calling the `Tagged` action like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagSlug))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Tagged", "Podcasts", new { tag = tagSlug });
}
```

> When I set a break point on the `Tagged`action, `tag` is always null

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the route but I can't figure out what...

Comment: @maccettura, I'm a relatively new programmer - could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: Can you share the code where you call 'Tagged' action?

Comment: @VinylWarmth I misread your post originally.  Ignore my previous comment.  Are you able to hit a breakpoint in your `Tagged` action when you hit the route?

Comment: For the record, you are not "passing a string to an action" when calling `RedirectToAction`. You are responding with an HTTP 302 response, which tells the browser to lookup a new location on your server with a string parameter. Obviously, if there is a way to pass the string directly for your use case it will be far more efficient than an extra round trip across the network. But if you need to the URL to change in the browser in addition to "passing the parameter", this is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a null is because you are not actually passing it a parameter called `tag` in your code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagSlug))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Tagged", "Podcasts", new { tagSlug });
}
```

When you omit the property name it takes the variable name, so you are actually passing a variable `tagSlug` which your action does not accept. Try this instead:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tagSlug))
{
    return RedirectToAction("Tagged", "Podcasts", new { tag = tagSlug });
}
```

Comment: So you do have a variable called `tag` that you pass?  Can we see where `tag` is being defined?

Comment: Please ignore my first comment, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It must be working exacly like this....

Then go to http://localhost:64147/podcast/tagged/hi and recive hi as a value of tag

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "MyRoute",
        url: "podcast/tagged/{tag}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Podcasts", action = "Tagged", tag = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry i'm asking here, but did you check that your route precedes any other routes that could overlay?

The routing is done by taking them in order. The first route that corresponds to the given parameters is chosen so if you have this route first

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

and then

```
Podcasts/Tagged/{tag}
```

you will get null because the first route is chosen

Route order actually matters

Comment: Hi, the action in my post is first the first route & the default action is last.